# JavaScript/d3 - Assign Attribute within Another Attribute

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'd like to assign some attributes/styles within an attribute definition with d3.  See the example below, which does work for me.  However, assigning an attribute within another attribute function just doesn't seem right.  Is there a better way to do it?

```
d3.selectAll('.myClass')
  .attr('x', function (d) {
    var myVar = some_expensive_function(d)
    if (myVar < 5) {
      d3.select(this).attr('class', 'myClass cssSelectorClass')
      // Assign other attributes or styles here too
      return myVar
    } else {
      d3.select(this).attr('class', 'myClass')
      // Assign other attributes or styles here too
      return myVar
    }
  })
```

I don't want to do the "expensive" calculation in each attribute function, so I'd rather not do something like:

```
d3.selectAll('.myClass')
  .attr('x', function (d) {
    var myVar = some_expensive_function(d)
    if (myVar < 5) {
      return myVar
    } else {
      return myVar
    }
  })
  .attr('class', function (d) {
    var myVar = some_expensive_function(d)
    if (myVar < 5) {
      return 'myClass cssSelectorClass'
    } else {
      return 'myClass'
    }
  })
```

Comment: Hm, I am somewhat reluctant voting to close this as duplicate of [*"Getting a better performance on repeatedly method on d3"*](/q/45993342). But if you really think twice, it comes down to the same problem, right?

Comment: Yes, it does.  I had not found that answer in my search.  Sounds like the solution it provides it essentially what I've done in my first example which is to use d3.select(this), albeit in a slightly cleaner way by using the each function.

Comment: @altocumulus it is a duplicate indeed.

Comment: @ScottB yes, you are correct: using `each` in this case is more idiomatic and clearer for whoever is reading your code.